Android Studio : The application could not be installed. Device went into offline mode after running MainActivity
I have been installing a debug app on my physical Android phone, but today it suddenly stopped working and showed this error: "The application could not be installed". There is no error log from Android Studio.
Observations:
Before running MainActivity from Android Studio, my device is listed as normal in adb devices.
After clicking the "Run" button to launch the app, Android Studio shows the error above after a few seconds.
The physical device is then removed from the running device list in Android Studio.
In adb devices, the physical device switches to offline mode.
Question:
It seems like a device issue at first, but I am not sure why running the app from Android Studio causes the device to go offline. What could be the solution for this?
**Physical device: **
Google Pixel 7, Android 14
Below are all troubleshoot steps I tried before running the app again and did not work:

Anroid Studio -> File -> Invalidate Cache and restart
Restart both my laptop and device
Developer options -> Revoke USB authorization
run adb kill-server and adb start-server
used another cord and try different port


Delete the existing app from the phone (if there is still one installed with the same packageName). Use Android Studio and build the APK. Then install it via  adb install. If this fails you will get an error message you can post here.

@Robert Thanks, deleting the existing app works for me. I realized that I had the old version of the app that was downloaded from app store which might caused this issue.
